# How to increase the values of decimal number to Positive real numbers

Tags: excel, google-sheets, ms-office, google-docs, libreoffice-calc

I have decimal numbers  in Google sheets like `95.84, 47.15, 78.32`
I want to increase it the nearest positive real numbers like

```
95.84 = 96
47.15 = 48
78.32 = 79
```

Is there any way to do this in Google sheets or even MS Office or LibreOffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `=ROUNDUP(A1,0)` function (Excel & Google Sheets).

[image]

Comment: Thank very match Kresimir it work in google sheets too you are life saver